# Top-down bottom-up

Tags: epistemology, reason, introduction-to-philosophy

I have seem the terms top-down bottom-up approach,top-down bottom-up models,top-down bottom-up causation in many papers.
I am bit confused.Are they really same or how can we define them ?

Comment: If you're seeing these phrases in essays about topics in a relatively specific domain of discourse (philosophy of science, I assume, per your tags), the authors do probably intend a lot of conceptual overlap/point-of-contact for using them. The prosocial dimension of science favors researchers who want to talk with, not past, each other (and provides for one of the indicators of pseudoscience: intellectually antisocial behavior, like aggressively cryptic writing modulo the target audience, seems to set off our "pseudoscience alarm").

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design)

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about the philosophy of science, 'top-down' approaches start with theory and then tries to produce observations through experimentation that validate that theory. 'Bottom-up' approaches begin by collating observations in the real world and trying to construct a theory from them. The terms are more or less synonymous with 'theory-driven' and 'data-driven'. In the philosophy of science it's generally seen as a chicken-or-egg question, since both approaches are frequently used in practice. It's mainly an academic question about which approach has primacy.

Comment: I think you are telling about deductive and inductive reasoning

Comment: @quanity: inductive and deductive reasoning play into the issue, yes.

Answer (score 3):

A bottom-up approach to understanding something is one in which the whole (the thing to be explained) is conceived solely as an effect. A top-down approach is one in which the whole is conceived as the cause.

Comment: Any examples of that

Comment: Any organic entity can serve as an example. You might start by reading section 64 and 65 of the Critique of Judgment.  https://www.gutenberg.org/files/48433/48433-h/48433-h.htm#s64

Comment: explain me distinction between effective causes and final causes and how its related to top down causation bottom up causation

Comment: Bottom-up causation is efficient. Top-down causation is final. 

https://youtu.be/8ZLgxwuFPek

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/sean-carrolls-mindscape-science-society-philosophy/id1406534739?i=1000507311173